# SVN Extract Changed Files With Php

Tags: php, svn

Is it possible to extract changed files between specified versions from same repo. And save them to any directory. I found svn_checkout function but it doesn't require my intention. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example lest's say you have two branches and the Trunk. You can switch to one branch ( svn switch branch1 ) and then compare that branch with a different one (branch2) like this:

svn diff PATH TO BRANCH2

Otherwise, if you only want to compare different revisions you can do something like this: svn diff -r REVISION_ID_1:REVISION_ID_2

With this methods you will find all affected files and then you can move them to a different folder or whatever.

Comment: good answer but i am confused about using branches and tags. There is one project in svn an my question is to take diff files by PHP on server for deployment purpose.

Comment: Ah ok... you can try with this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

`svn diff --summarize` will give you a list of the files that have changed between two revisions. Then use `svn cat` or `svn export` to pull them from your repository.